# Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider for API 19

Tags: android, android-multidex

When I using andorid version with API 27 it works fine, but when I tried running it with API 19 I got the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/se.dxapps.skidspar.beta-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/se.dxapps.skidspar.beta-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4793)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4385)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/se.dxapps.skidspar.beta-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/se.dxapps.skidspar.beta-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                           at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4778)
```

So I searched and tried a lot of suggestion to solve this, but none of them really works.

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
    }


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "se.dxapps.skidspar.beta"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false

        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26+'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.0'

    compile 'com.crittercism:crittercism-android-agent:+'
    compile 'com.felipecsl:gifimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

I have also changed to the most recent version of google gms services. This is how the build.gradle file look likes:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}


afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
        } else {
            dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have also added this line of code in the MainActivity to refelct for the API versions for where the DEX is not supported.

```
  @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super.attachBaseContext(context);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

And now Im out of ideas, do someone have another suggestion, or can see where the problem might be?

**EDIT**
I've tried and added a multiDexKeepFile that have these lines:

```
se/dxapps/skidspar/MainActivity.class
com/google/firebase/provider/FirebaseInitProvider.class
```

And placed this in the build.gradle

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex_keep_file.txt')
            minifyEnabled false
        }

        debug{
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex_keep_file.txt')
        }
    }
```

After executing and running the app I get this error:

```
Could not find method com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp, referenced from method com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate
12-17 12:16:40.270 4325-4325/se.dxapps.skidspar.beta W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static method 19752: Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp;.initializeApp (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp;
12-17 12:16:40.270 4325-4325/se.dxapps.skidspar.beta D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0004
12-17 12:16:40.270 4325-4325/se.dxapps.skidspar.beta D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-17 12:16:40.270 4325-4325/se.dxapps.skidspar.beta W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9cca1b20)
12-17 12:16:40.270 4325-4325/se.dxapps.skidspar.beta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: se.dxapps.skidspar.beta, PID: 4325
                                                                       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I haven't been able to solve this, and users are constantly feeding me with crash reports, and the only thing they have in common are that they are running on API 19 and getting this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException,"Didn't find class ""com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"" on path: DexPathList[[zip file ""/data/app/se.dxapps.skidspar.beta-2.apk""],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/se.dxapps.skidspar

Comment: It couldnt be that it searching for the zip file ""/data/app/se.dxapps.skidspar.beta-2.apk"? But should have instead searched for  "/data/app/se.dxapps.skidspar.beta.apk"?

Answer (score 0):

Multidex requires more build times and decisions in which it may exclude certain files. Try using `multiDexKeepFile` or `multiDexKeepProguard` property to preserve them from getting excluded.
Read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).

Comment: Ok, so I added the multiDexKeepFile and typed the following in this file:
se/dxapps/skidspar/MainActivity.class
com/google/firebase/provider/FirebaseInitProvider.class


But then I got the following error: 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp'

Comment: Exclude the whole Firebase package with a *

Comment: tried changing the firebase version in gradle to a newer or older one ?

Comment: Yep , did change to the same versions:
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'

Comment: why do you need both play services and firebase to be added separately ? If you're only using the messaging, just keep   `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2'` and nothing else